# A particle without gauge interactions

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, standard-model, gauge-theory, interactions

Please, Can anyone helps me to understand What does it mean a particle with no gauge interactions?

Comment: Do you understand what a “gauge interaction” is?

Comment: The 4-fermi interaction is not gauge, but is underlain by one such, like most interactions.

Comment: can you give a  link where you find the phrase used?

Comment: G.Smith, yes i do, but i will be happy if i get more information from you

Answer (score 1):

Sterile neutrinos do not have any gauge interaction (electroweak or strong) but only gravitational.